# I decided / have decided that I wanted a change from central London

Tags: grammar, tense, present-perfect, past-simple, exam-questions

The exercise below comes from my English textbook:

> Source: http://gymn1.baranovichi.edu.by/ru/main.aspx?guid=32441
>
> Decide which answer A, B, C or D best fits each space.
>
> Dear Linda,
>
> I’m sorry I haven't written to you for so long, but I have been very
>   busy lately. All last month I had exams, and I haven't done anything
>   else but study for ages. Anyway, I have stopped studying now., and I
>   am waiting for my exam results.
>
> As you can see from the letter, I have changed my address and live in
>   Corydon now. I __________ that I wanted a change from central London because
>   it has become so expensive. A friend of mine told me about this flat,
>   and I moved here about two months ago.
>
> When you come to London this summer, please visit me. I am staying
>   here until the middle of August. Then I am going on holiday to
>   Scotland.
>
> Please write soon,
>
> Margaret
>
> A. decided
>
> B. have decided
>
> C. was deciding
>
> D. decide

The given answer key is B (have decided). I think the author uses the present perfect in order to suggest that the decision made in the past is still of importance in the present.

Is it possible for me to choose A (decided) - the simple past tense? If so, is there any difference in the meaning between option A & B in this case?

Comment: Your book (or this exercise) was very obviously written by a non-native English speaker. If the "correct" answer have decided is used, the verb _want_ must be in the _present,_ not the _past_ tense: **I _have decided_ that I _want_ a change from central London because it has become so expensive.** If that error were corrected, B would be the correct answer, but with the error in place, only A is grammatically correct. **B** is the wrong answer.

Comment: @P.E.Dant: Thanks a lot. You are absolutely right. Fortunately, I found the original text which is from the book "First Certificate Language Practice", page 37 (the key is on page 323) (Link: http://www.slideshare.net/massaanalia/fce-language-practice). The authors of the book choose A (decided) as the correct answer.

Comment: I wish you good luck in explaining that to whoever screwed the exercise up at the Byelorussian site!

Comment: Yes, the "best"  choice (in American English) is *decided*. From the same language perspective, the present perfect is more likely only if *want* is in the present, not  past tense. However, and here is why it says the "best answer", all four given verb tenses (including the present perfect with *wanted*)  can be  grammatically correct in that sentence, but we've talked about which two would be most likely.

Comment: @doquan0 It's important that you understand that (contrary to my first comment) all four choices could be interpreted as _correct._ As AlanCarmack points out, the exercise asks for the _best_ answer, not the _correct_ one.

Comment: Could we really say **As you can see from the letter, I have changed my address and live in Croydon now. I decide that I wanted a change ...**? In isolation we could accept that **decide** would be grammatical, and perhaps be part of some larger narrative. In this context, following **I have have changed my address** the switch to present tense seems very odd to me.

Comment: _Correct_ here means _not in blatant violation of the rules of grammar,_ @djna. The exercise asks for the _best,_ which is this case is _the least bad._ Since he seems to have analyzed it in depth, I take AlanCarmack's word that the sentence you cite could somehow be parsed as conforming to grammatical strictures. It isn't a very good sentence, obviously.